# Polymer routes not working Polymer starter kit

Tags: .htaccess, polymer, url-routing, polymer-starter-kit

I cloned polymer starter kit and its working perfectly fine.

So in the placeholder route there is a page called 
http://localhost:5000/users/Rob. 
The above url works if I move from users page to Rob page by clicking on the rob link.

but if I directly paste on http://localhost:5000/users/Rob on browser and press enter, it does not work.

I assume the above might be resolved by using htaccess. but couldn't figure out how.

Below is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

try http://localhost:5000/#!/users/Rob.

[#! hashtag and exclamation mark in links as folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871224/hashtag-and-exclamation-mark-in-links-as-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Removing `[L,R=302]` did the trick for me!

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /
```

**index.html:**

```html
<app-route
route="{{route}}"
pattern="/users/:id"
data="{{usersRouteData}}"
tail="{{usersSubroute}}"
active="{{usersActive}}"
></app-route>
```